# Chat storage in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, logging, chat, mysql-python

My friend and I run an IRC chat for a group of our friends, problem is that the history deletes  when you log in, and doesn't store it anywhere, so when we try to reference something said earlier, the other user cannot see it, plus we often post links for us all to refer to later.

I would like to start archiving the chat on my personal site into the mySQL, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing this other than manually. Is there a way to have a persistent scraper add to my database whenever someone posts?

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's a fantastic solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too broad question. You don't want a Scraper, what you want is a "bot" a simple server that resides in your chat channel and listens.
There are several solutions for python mIRC bots.
Here is one: [Echo](https://gist.github.com/RobertSzkutak/1326452).
It is very crude, there are several things that can be done to make it more elegant, but as a simplest solution it is ok